# Create an immutable map from a collection of pairs in Xtend

Tags: collections, xtend

I have a collection of objects `O` from which I want to create an (immutable) map of two features (say, `O.name` and `O.value`).

My best solution so far is

```
newHashMap(o.map[it.name -> it.value])
```

But this will instantiate and initialize a new `HashMap` which is not acually what I want. Instead I want an immutable map without unneeded instantiation, similarly what

```
o.toInvertedMap[value]
```

returns - but this maps `O` to `O.value`.

Is there a method in the Xtend library to achieve what I want?

*Note: to add some context to my general question above, I actually want to get a map of attribute names and values for my EMF `EObject`s:*

```
newHashMap(eObject.eClass.EAttributes.map[it.name -> eObject.eGet(it).toString])
```

**Edit:**

I just found this:

```
newImmutableMap(o.map[it.name -> it.value])
```

This seems more like what I want. Is this the "best" way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found so far is (as in the Update above):

```
newImmutableMap(o.map[name->value])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o.map[name->value].toImmutableMap?
```

Comment: `o.map[name->value]` yields a `List<Pair<?,?>>`. As far as I can see, there is no extension method `toMap` or `toImmutableMap` for this. (there is `toMap(computeKeysFunction)`, but this is not usable to convert a list of pairs to a map.